# Tkinter keyboard buttons add letters to Entry

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, keyboard

I'm trying to write a code for my GUI. I want a keyboard that adds a letter to the Entry widget. I'm close to it but the problem is that its adding to the entry only the letter 'a' when clicking on the buttons .

As you see in my code i added 'a' to the command. command=lambda: set_text('a')
Ofcourse is this the reason why its printing 'a' only. But if i take letter from the forloop and make set_text(letter) its showing only H in the Entry widget.

I try'd also to remove the second loop change it to set_text(lst[count])
All buttons are adding now  'A' to the Entry.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

my code:

```
    from tkinter import *
from ttk import *

def maakbuttons():
    count = 0
    lst = []
    if count <= 7:
        for letter in 'ABCDEFGH':
            lst.append(letter)
        for letter in lst:
            Buttons = Button(master=root, text=letter, command=lambda: set_text('a'))
            Buttons.place(x=20, y=30 +50 * count)
            count+=1

def set_text(text):
    a = e.get() + text
    e.delete(0, len(e.get()))
    e.insert(0, a)


def remove_letter():
    last = len(e.get())-1
    if last >= 0:
        e.delete(last)


root= Tk()



a = root.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', 1)

e = Entry(root,width=10)
e.place(x=500, y=500)

maakbuttons()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Repalce your line with:

```
 Buttons = Button(master=root, text=letter, command=lambda x=letter: set_text(x))
```

Also:

```
for letter in 'ABCDEFGH':
    lst.append(letter)
for letter in lst:
   ...
```

Seems to be redundant.

Comment: Thanks man! I replaced the Buttons line with yours and now it works fine. What did you mean with for letter in 'ABC...':?